# Formating grep output

Tags: grep, output

I have website on my hard drive that I need to locate keywords within the HTML files, then output to an html file, listing each find on a new line. Currently i'm useing the line below, but the output is not ideal.

```
grep -lUirn  -C 1  "Word1" *  >> report.html
```

the above line produces something like:

```
      file1.html file2.html etc.html
```

but i need it to output to the file as:

```
      file1.html 

      file2.html 

      etc.html
```

even more ideal would be to output it as:

```
      http://relitivePath/file1.html 

      http://relitivePath/file2.html 

      http://relitivePath/etc.html
```

Comment: Welcome to U/L. I'm quite confused by your question. The `-l` flag outputs the name of the matching file, but it *should* output one filename per line. (Is that what you want?) I'm not sure what the `-n` option does here. Since you are only outputting filenames, I don't think it does anything. We also don't know the rules to derive the "relitivePath" from the original filenames.

Comment: "relitivePath"  is not critical, whats critical is getting the output to individual lines instead of a continues line without CR's

Comment: I just noticed you also have `-C` which also makes no sense with `-l`. I can't replicate this behaviour. I create the files with `for i in {1..3}; do echo Word1 > file$i.html; done`, then `grep -lUirn  -C 1  "Word1"` puts each filename on a separate line. What version of `grep` are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using GNU `grep`, the `-U` option (treat all files as binary) has no effect unless you are running on MS-DOS or Windows, and `-n` (output line numbers of matching lines) has no effect when combined with `-l` (output only the names of the matching files).  Likewise, `-C 1` (a single line of context around the match) does not have any effect with `-l`.

The matched files are already reported on separate lines, so I don't quite see why you get them on a single line.

```
grep -lr -Fiw 'Word1' .
```

should do what you want.  I added `-F` to do string comparisons instead of regular expression matches, and `-w` to do matching of complete words (not substrings).

To convert the output to URIs:

```
grep -lr -Fiw 'Word1' . | sed 's,^,http://,'
```

This just inserts `http://` at the start of each line using `sed`.

All of this obviously assumes that no filename contains any embedded newlines.  If they did, `sed` would insert its string before each newline-delimited part of the filename.

Comment: Your syntax adds the http:// nicely but i'm still getting everything concatenated together. How do i add CR after each line?

Comment: @David What Unix are you running? `grep -l` should output one single pathname per line, always.  I'm as confused [as Sparhawk](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/513514/formating-grep-output/513523?noredirect=1#comment949635_513514) as to why your `grep -l` does not output one filename per line.

Comment: I'm using OS X at the moment

Comment: @David Well, I tested on macOS Mojave, and `grep -l` definitely does not output multiple filenames per line. Do you have a single file called literally `file1.html file2.html etc.html` with spaces inbetween?

Comment: I found my error. In a text editor LF's show, but opening in browser did not. I spaced on adding <br>.  This solved my issue.   grep -lr -Fiw 'word' * | sed 's,^,<BR>http://,'  >>  Report.html        Thanks for the help everyone!